# onEdit() to exclude header row

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, offset

I've been reading through various posts on how to exclude the header row from my `onEdit()`. I have read examples of `offset()` and I even use `shift()` in my other functions. This particular one is to generate a checkbox when a range in a row has value.

I have tried the following, separately:

`checkboxCell.offset(1,0)`

`checkboxCell.shift()`

These end up as failures with messages saying they are not functions.

Could someone guide me as to how this can be done?

```
function onEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const checkboxCell = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1);
  let editedRow = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
  editedRow = editedRow.filter(x => x != '');
  if (editedRow.length == 3) {
    checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
  } else {
    checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
    checkboxCell.clearContent();
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide your current output and also your expected output in your question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Tuna. Currently, my checkboxes are in column A when columns B-D have values but the script also overrides A1 and turns that header cell into a checkbox. The checkboxes are meant to only start on row 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Add another conditional statement to restrict adding a checkbox if the `e.range.rowStart` is set to 1 (which is the first row)

**Full code:**

```
function onEdit(e) {

  let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  const checkboxCell = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 1);
  let editedRow = sheet.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 2, 1, 3).getValues().flat();
  editedRow = editedRow.filter(x => x != '');
  
  if (editedRow.length == 3 && e.range.rowStart != 1) {
    checkboxCell.insertCheckboxes();
  } else {
    checkboxCell.clearDataValidations();
    checkboxCell.clearContent();
  }

}
```

**Modification:**

from `(editedRow.length == 3)` to `(editedRow.length == 3 && e.range.rowStart != 1)`

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, Tuna!

I took your idea and added  to the `else{}`.


From `} else {` to `}else if(e.range.rowStart != 1) {`


This solves the issue of the A1 header cell being cleared in addition to it being overriden with a checkbox.